# Rewrite in Nginx for hostname:82

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am facing redirection issue while setup a instance on Nginx+tomcat
I am using nginx with haproxy with tomcat

Below is my configuration which i am using for setup a virtual host [under conf.d]

```
    server{
            listen 82;
            server_name domain.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://$server_name$1 permanent;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;
     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:100;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   }
```

Now when i am putting http://domain.com:82 on browser this redirects to https://domain.com
and i want to keep it on :82 port

I also tried the below rewrite rule but didn't solve the problem [This is not opening the page]

**rewrite ^(.*)   http://$server_name:82/$1 permanent**

Please help me to rectify this issue.

Thanks,
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just made an error in port number? 81 instead of 82?

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially created an infinite loop. NGINX is already listening to :82 due to `listen 82;`. Every time a request comes in, it's just reinitializing the request. You should be able to remove (or comment out) the `rewrite ^/(.*) http://$server_name$1 permanent;` line for it to work properly.

Comment: Hello Sean

thanks for the useful information. However when i am accessing the application using this port i am able to login but on clicking any link inside the app, it redirect me to the login page again, after removing the line mentioned by you....
this app is a copy of another app which is running on port 80 (working fine) and the issue is with copied app which is on :81. Is this is a issue of app or there is a nginx conf issue to maintain JSESSIONID as app is deployed on tomcat.

Please help me.